# How to plot to describe the density characteristics of a dataset?

Tags: r, plot, probability-density

I have datasets which consist of 263 users.
It has the following  data frame structure:

```
userID  bookmarkID  tagID   value
1   52  101 1
1   114 154 1
2   127 14  1
4   114 4   1
```

For each user, I calculate the value of a variable representing frequency by this equation:
count() / (number of bookmarkIDs * number of tagIDs).I got these values:
 The number from 1 to 265 are just user IDs and the users are not ordered.

```
            1            2            3            4            5            6 
    0.0003716331 0.0005655286 0.0001777376 0.0003070012 0.0019389552 0.0002746853 
    ...
    ...
             259          260          261          262          263          264 
    0.0003393172 0.0006463184 0.0002100535 0.0002100535 0.0001777376 0.0004685808 
             265 
    0.0001777376
```

Using the following R codes:

```
#each user: number of tensor elements which >0 / (num of tags* number of items)
d.file <-
  "E:/My_Projects/Bitbucket/TylerRecommender/src/test/resources/DAI_LAbor/p-core of level 12/dataFilePathBeforeTensorDecompositionForTraining80percent.txt"
df<-read.table(d.file,sep="\t",header=T)

itemsize<-length(unique(df$bookmarkID))
tagsize<-length(unique(df$tagID))
itemtagmatrixsize<-itemsize*tagsize

userid.bag<-df$userID
user.tas.count<-table(userid.bag)
dens.tas<-density(user.tas.count/itemtagmatrixsize)
plot(dens.tas, col="red")

d.file2 <-
  "E:/My_Projects/Bitbucket/TylerRecommender/src/test/resources/DAI_LAbor/p-core of level 12/~sample_tensor_afterDecomposition_Condensed.example.txt"
df2<-read.table(d.file2,sep="\t",header=T)
lines(density(table(df2$userID)/itemtagmatrixsize), col="blue")
```

**Now my problem is how can I plot a graph to best describe the frequency distribution of the users?**

I am using kernel density estimation function density() in R to plot the frequency values' probability distribution. (Is this meeting my objective? )

[image]

Howverever, I have another dataset which has much higher frequency values than the previous one (blue) in the following graph, in which the red line is related to the previous dataset:
[image]

But the red line for the first dataset became totally flat which is meaningless. Why is that? Is it because of the default chosen bandwidth? Is it possible to plot them in the same graph and make they looking normal?
Thanks!

Comment: compare the two y-axes.  Looks like it one needs `prob = TRUE` or just a simple `ylim` adjustment

Comment: But the X values (frequency values of the two datasets) are all fixed. Can I adjust Y? What do you mean?

Comment: Can you show us your code to generate the two graphs?